# saveToCassandra works with Cassandra Lucene plugin?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, lucene, cassandra-lucene-index

I am implementing the example on Lucene plugin for Cassandra page (https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) and when I try to save the data using saveToCassandra I get the exception NoSuchElementException.
 If I use CassandraConnector.withSessionDo I am able to add elements into Cassandra and no exception is raised.

The tables:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo
WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
USE demo;
CREATE TABLE tweets (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user TEXT,
    body TEXT,
    time TIMESTAMP,
    latitude FLOAT,
    longitude FLOAT
);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX tweets_index ON tweets ()
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'refresh_seconds' : '1',
    'schema' : '{
        fields : {
            id    : {type : "integer"},
            user  : {type : "string"},
            body  : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
            time  : {type : "date", pattern : "yyyy/MM/dd", sorted : true},
            place : {type : "geo_point", latitude:"latitude", longitude:"longitude"}
        }
    }'
};
```

The code :

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, Logging}
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object App extends Logging{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        // Get the cassandra IP and create the spark context
        val cassandraIP = System.getenv("CASSANDRA_IP");
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
                        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraIP)
                        .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "3600")
                        .setAppName("Simple Spark Cassandra Example")


        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

        // Works
        CassandraConnector(sparkConf).withSessionDo { session =>
           session.execute("INSERT INTO demo.tweets(id, user, body, time, latitude, longitude) VALUES (19, 'Name', 'Body', '2016-03-19 09:00:00-0300', 39, 39)")
        }

        // Does not work
        val demo = sc.parallelize(Seq((9, "Name", "Body", "2016-03-29 19:00:00-0300", 29, 29)))
        // Raises the exception
        demo.saveToCassandra("demo", "tweets", SomeColumns("id", "user", "body", "time", "latitude", "longitude"))

    }
}
```

The exception:

```
16/03/28 14:15:41 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Column  not found in demo.tweets
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.StructDef$$anonfun$columnByName$2.apply(Schema.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.StructDef$$anonfun$columnByName$2.apply(Schema.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Map$WithDefault.default(Map.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$9.apply(Schema.scala:153)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$9.apply(Schema.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef.<init>(Schema.scala:152)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:283)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4.foreach(Set.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1(Schema.scala:271)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:295)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:294)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:275)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.webradar.spci.spark.cassandra.App$.main(App.scala:27)
    at com.webradar.spci.spark.cassandra.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)    16/03/28 14:15:41 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Column  not found in demo.tweets
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.StructDef$$anonfun$columnByName$2.apply(Schema.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.StructDef$$anonfun$columnByName$2.apply(Schema.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Map$WithDefault.default(Map.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$9.apply(Schema.scala:153)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$9.apply(Schema.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef.<init>(Schema.scala:152)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:283)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4.foreach(Set.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1(Schema.scala:271)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:295)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:294)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:275)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.webradar.spci.spark.cassandra.App$.main(App.scala:27)
    at com.webradar.spci.spark.cassandra.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

EDITED:
Versions

- Spark 1.6.0
- Cassandra 3.0.3
- Lucene plugin 3.0.3.1
- For Jar creation I used maven-assembly-plugin to get a fat JAR.

If I remove the custom index I am able to use saveToCassandra

Comment: Couple of questions... Which versions of spark, cassandra connector are you using? and how do you submit your jar? is it a jar or fat jar?

Comment: I added the versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by a problem in the Cassandra Spark driver, and not in the plugin.

Since [CASSANDRA-10217](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10217)  Cassandra 3.x per-row indexes don't require to be created on a fake column anymore. Thus, from Cassandra 3.x the "**CREATE CUSTOM INDEX %s ON %s(%s)**" column-based syntax is replaced with the new "**CREATE CUSTOM INDEX %s ON %s()**" row-based syntax.  However, DataStax Spark driver doesn't seem to support this new feature yet.

When "*com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra*" is called it tries to load the table schema and the index schema related to a table column. Since this new index syntax does not have the fake-column anymore it results in a NoSuchElementException due to an empty column name.

However, saveToCassandra works well if you execute the same example with prior fake column syntax:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo
WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
USE demo;
CREATE TABLE tweets (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user TEXT,
    body TEXT,
    time TIMESTAMP,
    latitude FLOAT,
    longitude FLOAT,
    lucene TEXT
);



CREATE CUSTOM INDEX tweets_index ON tweets (lucene)
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'refresh_seconds' : '1',
    'schema' : '{
        fields : {
            id    : {type : "integer"},
            user  : {type : "string"},
            body  : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
            time  : {type : "date", pattern : "yyyy/MM/dd", sorted : true},
            place : {type : "geo_point", latitude:"latitude", longitude:"longitude"}
        }
    }'
};
```